# ¿Como hacer una consulta de una tabla con llaves foráneas de un determinado id?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Cordial saludos, el problema que tengo es sobre una consulta. Quiero que me busque todos los abonos de un prestamo en especifico. La consulta que tengo me arroja son todos los abonos de todos los prestamos, la verdad no se cual es el error logico.

me puse a ejecutar el sql con phpmyadmin y me funciona me trae solo los abonos de un prestamo especifico pero cuando la ejecuto con el id_prestamo que traigo del formulario no me lo lista, si no me lista todos. Dedusco que hay algo que esta fallando en el paso del id_prestamo al listado del archivo abonos.php

**Esta es la base de datos**:[image: Base de datos relacional]

Este archivo **prestamos.php** donde lista todos los prestamos y tiene un enlace donde dice "ver abonos" que es donde me lleva al archivo **abono_esepcifico.php** donde hace el proceso de mostrar solo los abonos del determinado prestamo y me lleva al listado de los abonos al archivo **abonos.php**

Este es el archivo **prestamos.php** :

```
<?php

require('../conexion.php');
include('../menu/menu.php');
$con=Conectar();

//recibimos variable que llegan por metodo post o en el arreglo post
extract ($_REQUEST);
if (!isset ($_REQUEST['x'])) // si se desconoce la variable x se asigna el 
valor de 0
$x=0;

$sql="SELECT id_prestamo, pre_cliente, fecha, monto, forma_de_pago, fiador, 
cliente.cedula,cliente.nombre, cliente.apellido from prestamo
inner join cliente
on prestamo.pre_cliente=cliente.id_cliente
ORDER BY id_prestamo ASC";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Prestamos</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="wid=device-wid, user-scalable=no, initial-
scale=1.0, minium-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
<div class="container col-lg-12" >
<br>
<div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading" align="center"><h3>PRESTAMOS</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">

<div class="row" align="center">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-
target="#nuevo">
Nuevo prestamo
</button></div>
<br>

<!--      clase para colocar tabla responsive-->
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="grid" class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered 
nowrap dt-responsive" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr class="active">

<th>Cedula</th>
<th>Cliente</th>
<th>Monto $ </th>
<th>No Cuotas</th>
<th>Interes %</th>
<th>Fecha Prestamo</th>
<th>Fiador</th>
<th>Forma de pago</th>
<th>Saldo actual</th>
<th>Abonos</th>
<th>Opciones</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<?php

$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$resultado=$stmt->execute();
$rows=$stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($rows as $prestamo) {

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->cedula?></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->nombre." ".$prestamo->apellido?></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->monto?></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->fecha?></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->fiador?></td>
<td><?php echo $prestamo->forma_de_pago?></td>
<td></td>

// este es el enlace que me lleva al archivo para hacer el proceso del query

<td><a href="../abonos/abono_especifico.php?id_prestamo=<?php echo 
$prestamo->id_prestamo ?>">Ver abonos</a>

&nbsp;
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><a 
href="../abonos/frm_abonar.php?id_prestamo=<?php echo $prestamo->id_prestamo 
?>" style="text-decoration: none; color:#000;" >Abonar</button></a>
</td>
<td align="center"><a href="frm_editar.php?id_prestamo=<?php echo $prestamo-
>id_prestamo?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" title="Editar">
</span></a>
&nbsp;
<a href="eliminar.php?id_prestamo= <?php echo $prestamo->id_prestamo?>">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Eliminar"></span></a></td>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div align="center">
<br /><br />

<?php
if ($x==1) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Se actualizado el prestamo 
correctamente</div>';
}
if ($x==2) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" data-dismiss="alert" 
style="width:300px">Problemas al actualizar el prestamo</div>';
}
if ($x==3) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Se ha eliminado el prestamo 
correctamente</span>';
}
if ($x==4) {
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Problemas al eliminar el prestamo,  
Primero elimina el prestamo</div>';
}
if ($x==5){
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Se ha agregado el prestamo correctamente 
</div>';
}
if ($x==6){
echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" data-
dismiss="alert" style="width:300px">Problemas al agregar el prestamo</div>';
}
?>
</div>       
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Este es el archivo donde realizo las consulta:

**abono_especifico.php**

```
<?php

//archivo para la conexion
require "../conexion.php";
$con=Conectar();

$prestamo=$_REQUEST['id_prestamo'];

$sql="SELECT a.id_abono, a.abo_prestamo, a.fecha, a.cantidad, a.observacion, 
p.pre_cliente, c.cedula,c.nombre, c.apellido from abono a, prestamo p, 
cliente c
where a.abo_prestamo='$prestamo'
and p.pre_cliente=c.id_cliente
ORDER BY id_abono ASC";


$resultado=$con->prepare($sql);

$resultado->execute();


if ($resultado){
header ("location: abonos.php?x=7");//x=5 abonos encontrado
}else{
header ("location: abonos.php?x=8");//x=6 error al buscar el abono
}
$resultado->closeCursor();
?>
```

Este es el archivo que me lista los abonos, **abonos.php**

```
<?php

require('../conexion.php');
include('../menu/menu.php');
$con=Conectar();

//recibimos variable que llegan por metodo post o en el arreglo post
extract ($_REQUEST);
if (!isset ($_REQUEST['x'])) // si se desconoce la variable x se asigna el 
valor de 0
$x=0;

$sql="SELECT a.id_abono, a.abo_prestamo, a.fecha, a.cantidad, a.observacion, 
p.pre_cliente, c.cedula,c.nombre, c.apellido from abono a, prestamo p, 
cliente c
where a.abo_prestamo=p.id_prestamo
and p.pre_cliente=c.id_cliente
ORDER BY id_abono ASC";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Abonos</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="wid=device-wid, user-scalable=no, initial-
scale=1.0, minium-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" >
<br>
<div class="panel panel-success">
<div class="panel-heading" align="center"><h3>ABONOS</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="grid" class="table  table-bordered  table-hover table-condensed">
<thead>
<tr class="active">
<th>Cedula</th>
<th>Cliente</th>
<th>Descripcion</th>
<th>Fecha</th>
<th>Abono $</th>
<th >Saldo $</th>
<th>Opciones</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<?php
$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
$resultado=$stmt->execute();
$rows=$stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($rows as $abono) {
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $abono->cedula?></td>
<td><?php echo $abono->nombre. " ".$abono->apellido?></td>
<td><?php echo $abono->observacion?></td>
<td><?php echo $abono->fecha?></td>
<td><?php echo $abono->cantidad?></td>
<td></td>

<td align="center"><a href="frm_editar.php?id_prestamo=<?php echo $prestamo-
>id_prestamo?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" title="Editar">
</span></a>
&nbsp;

<a href="eliminar.php?id_prestamo= <?php echo $prestamo->id_prestamo?>">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Eliminar"></span></a></td>

<?php
}
?>

</tr>
</table>
<div align="center">
<br /><br />

<?php
if ($x==1) {
echo '<span style="color:black">Se actualizado el Abono 
correctamente</span>';
}
if ($x==2) {
echo '<span style="color:black">Problemas al actualizar el Abono</span>';
}
if ($x==3) {
echo '<span style="color:black">Se ha eliminado el Abono 
correctamente</span>';
}
if ($x==4) {
echo '<span style="color:black">Problemas al eliminar el Abono</span';
}
if ($x==5){
echo '<span style="color:black">Se ha agregado el Abono 
correctamente</span';
}
if ($x==6){
echo '<span style="color:black">Problemas al agregar el Abono</span>';
}
if ($x==7){
echo '<span style="color:black">Abonos encontrados</span>';
}
if ($x==8){
echo '<span style="color:black">Problema al encontrar los abonos</span>';
}
?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Por ultimo dejo el archivo de **conexion.php**

```
<?php

function Conectar(){
$conn=null;
$host='localhost';
$db='prestamos';
$us='root';
$pass='';

try {
    $conn= new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $us, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo ":( Error al conectar a la base de datos".$e;
    exit;
}
return $conn;
}

?>
```

Se les agradecería una pronta respuesta.

Comment: Como que tu problemática parece más de crear una consulta que de crear código, sería mejor que agregaras tu modelo ER de las tablas, tu consulta, los datos que esta te arroja y los datos que tú esperas arroje.

Comment: amigo tu pregunta es super amplia

Comment: @Lixus Creo que me extendi mucho pero lo que tu dices ahi esta: en la imagen esta el modelo ER y la consulta que tengo esta en el archivo: abono_especifico.php pero o que me arroja esa consulta son todos los abonos y no el abono especifico de un prestamo. Que lo ultimo que es lo que deseo hacer.

Comment: @CriticalGhost Solo quiero saber como hago la consulta para traer un abono de un préstamo en especifico. Espero que me haga entender.

Comment: @Juanzu si pero la consulta es en sql, no es necesario colocar el codigo de los archivos que tienes

Comment: @CriticalGhost En cierta parte tienes razón pero quería que vieran de donde sale el Get del id_prestamo y también como esta estructurado el código donde enlaza el prestamos ya que esta tienes dos llaves foráneas.

Comment: mmm bueno yo creo que es una consulta normalita pero no sabre decirte

Comment: @CriticalGhost pues ahi tengo la consulta pero me arroja son todos los abonos de todos los prestamos, y solo quiero los abonos de un préstamo en especifico.

Comment: ahhhhh sencillo entonces, donde esta la consulta por cierto, podrias agregarlo en la pregunta

Comment: @CriticalGhost Ahi esta, en el archivo: **abono_especifico.php**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto es lo que necesitas.

Verás que la consulta utiliza `JOINS` en vez de usar `WHERE`, porque es recomendable usar este tipo de uniones, son más eficaces y menos costosas.

Sencillamente los `JOINS` unen las tablas por las llaves primarias/foráneas de cada una y traen los registros.

Es un ejemplo básico el cual puedes adaptar, aplicando los filtros, orden, columnas, agrupaciones que quieras.

En el ejemplo se consultan los abonos que hechos el prestamo con el `id_prestamo = 1`.

---

### [DEMO SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b747d6/3)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente
    (`id_cliente` int, `nom_cliente` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO cliente
    (`id_cliente`, `nom_cliente`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro'),
    (2, 'Santiago'),
    (3, 'Juan')
;

CREATE TABLE prestamo
    (`id_prestamo` int, `pre_cliente` int, `monto` float)
;

INSERT INTO prestamo
    (`id_prestamo`, `pre_cliente`, `monto`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1000.00),
    (2, 2, 23000.00),
    (3, 3, 1000000.10)
;

CREATE TABLE abono
    (`id_abono` int, `abo_prestamo` int, `cantidad` float)
;

INSERT INTO abono
    (`id_abono`, `abo_prestamo`, `cantidad`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 100.00),
    (2, 2, 300.00),
    (3, 3, 1500.00),
    (4, 1, 200.00)   
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  c.nom_cliente, p.id_prestamo, a.id_abono, a.cantidad
FROM 
  prestamo p

  LEFT JOIN cliente c ON p.pre_cliente=c.id_cliente
  LEFT JOIN abono a ON p.id_prestamo=a.abo_prestamo

  WHERE p.id_prestamo=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b747d6/3/0)**:

```
| nom_cliente | id_prestamo | id_abono | cantidad |
|-------------|-------------|----------|----------|
|       Pedro |           1 |        1 |      100 |
|       Pedro |           1 |        4 |      200 |
```

**NOTA**:

Sobre tu código PHP quiero señalar que el mismo es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL, ya que no es una buena práctica enviar juntas a la base de datos la consulta y los datos, se recomienda usar consultas preparadas que separen lo que es la instrucción SQL y los datos.

Por ejemplo, esta consulta es vulnerable a la inyección SQL:

```
$sql="SELECT a.id_abono, a.abo_prestamo, a.fecha, a.cantidad, a.observacion, 
p.pre_cliente, c.cedula,c.nombre, c.apellido from abono a, prestamo p, 
cliente c
where a.abo_prestamo=p.id_prestamo
and p.pre_cliente=c.id_cliente
ORDER BY id_abono ASC";
```

Significa que en ella se puede introducir código malicioso y se ejecutaría tal cual, pudiendo tener consecuencias desastrosas.

Entonces habría que prepararla, por ejemplo:

```
$sql="SELECT a.id_abono, a.abo_prestamo, a.fecha, a.cantidad, a.observacion, 
p.pre_cliente, c.cedula,c.nombre, c.apellido from abono a, prestamo p, 
cliente c
where a.abo_prestamo=?
and p.pre_cliente=?
ORDER BY id_abono ASC";
```

Lo que se hace en una consulta preparada es **sustituir los datos que vienen de fuera por signos de interrogación** (hay otros métodos) y luego enviar esos datos **por otro lado, a través de binding**. Es un tema un poco largo, te recomiendo que leas el enlace indicado más abajo.

El problema es que si en esta consulta el valor que envías para `c.id_cliente` es tomado de un formulario y un usuario malicioso escribe esto: `1; DELETE FROM cliente; #` estaría enviando un id_cliente igual a uno y al mismo tiempo una consulta para borrar tu tabla clientes, comentando con el signo de `#` todo el resto de la consulta (`ORDER BY id_abono ASC`) y tu tabla clientes sería borrada indefectiblemente. Eso es lo que se llama **Inyección SQL**.

Para más detalles sobre esto consulta esta pregunta y sus respuestas: [**¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)

Comment: Interesante los consejos que me das, me puse a ejecutar el sql con phpmyadmin y me funciona me trae solo los abonos de un prestamo especifico pero cuando la ejecuto con el id_prestamo que traigo del formulario no me lo lista, si no me lista todos. Dedusco que hay algo que esta fallando en el paso del id_prestamo al listado del archivo abonos.php

Comment: @Juanzu Si te funciona en PHPMyAdmin y no en PHP, ha de ser que se está tomando algún parámetro mal en los formularios o algo por el estilo, supongo que la `$sql` que estás ejecutando es una como la que te muestro en **Query 1** de la respuesta. Cuando algo falla yo suelo imprimir la variable `$sql`, y los valores que se supone debería tener, a veces hay errores de escritura en la cadena o de recuperación de los datos del formulario.

Comment: Si, de hecho imprime la variable y me imprime la id correcta con sus respectivos campos. Yo estoy seguro que el inconveniente es que me muestra la busqueda en el archivo: abonos.php.  Pero entonces ahi el problemas por que quiero que los muestre ahi y no me toque hacer otra tablar donde me liste los datos. Igual se te agredece.

Comment: No te entiendo... en el archivo `abono.php` no veo que en ningún momento asignas el `id_prestamo` recuperado en el `$_REQUEST['x']` a la consulta. Estoy seguro que si, para probar escribes la consulta manual y se la mandas a la BD funcionaría. Algo como: `SELECT  c.nom_cliente, p.id_prestamo, a.id_abono, a.cantidad FROM   prestamo p   LEFT JOIN cliente c ON p.pre_cliente=c.id_cliente   LEFT JOIN abono a ON p.id_prestamo=a.abo_prestamo   WHERE p.id_prestamo=1`, con un número arbitrario. El problema debe ser que no recuperas bien la variable id o no la envías bien.

Comment: Si, es que no se como recuperarlo ya que ahi es donde se listan los abonos agregados, editados y eliminados. La verdad no se como realizarlo.

Comment: @Juanzu En realidad son dos preguntas en una, por una parte la forma de hacer la consulta a la bd con los joins correctos. Por otra parte el código PHP. Creo que es mejor, si has comprobado que la SQL funciona en PHPMyAdmin, des por resuelta esta parte del problema y que plantees una nueva pregunta relativa al funcionamiento del código PHP, poniendo en ella solamente la parte del código que te está fallando. Si no aquí puede uno pasarse horas haciendo pruebas. El problema ahora es que no estás recuperando bien la id en el archivo php.

Comment: Claro, como te dije anteriormente la consulta si funciona, lo que no funciona es que me diriga al listado de los abonos en el archivo abonos.php. y ya dejare esta pregunta aqui y formulare otra, Dios te bendiga.

Comment: @Juanzu Es mejor así, y coloca en la nueva pregunta solamente el código donde envías el id del préstamo y el código que lo recibe. Y para que esta pregunta no quede abierta, si consideras que la parte SQL queda solucionada con esta u otra respuesta puedes marcarla como solucionado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Nunca haces el join con la tabla de prestamo, y cliente y abono no tienen relación directa, quizá por ahí vaya, cambia tu consulta por

```
$sql="SELECT a.id_abono, a.abo_prestamo, a.fecha, a.cantidad, a.observacion, 
p.pre_cliente, c.cedula,c.nombre, c.apellido from abono a, prestamo p, 
cliente c
where a.abo_prestamo='$prestamo'
and a.abo_prestamo = p.id_prestamo
and p.pre_cliente=c.id_cliente
ORDER BY id_abono ASC";
```

En lo personal prefiero los inner join pero aun así como lo puse ya debería funcionar ya que tiene la relación.

Answer (score -1):

No me he parado a leer el código porque ni se php, ni parece que el problema resida ahí, sino en tu consulta.

Echándole un ojo veo que te falta la condición de **unión** de de las tablas **abono** y **prestamo**:

```
    SELECT a.id_abono, a.abo_prestamo, a.fecha, a.cantidad, a.observacion, p.pre_cliente, c.cedula,c.nombre, c.apellido 

FROM abono a, prestamo p, cliente c

WHERE a.abo_prestamo='$prestamo' AND p.pre_cliente=c.id_cliente AND a.abo_prestamo=p.id_prestamo
ORDER BY id_abono ASC
```

Comment: No entiendo por que repites la unión de abono préstamo con el id_prestamo? me explicas?